# What is a good practice when setting www vs. non-www server (apache)?

Tags: apache-2.4, www

I have tried to configure a non-www website on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache 2.4 and I've managed to make things work, my https://example.me works fine. But, [www.example.me](http://www.example.me) subdomain is also active (because I've added ServerAlias).
The https://www.example.me opens as well and shows no certificate which makes me confused - shouldn't it redirect to https://example.com ?
What is a good practice here - should I have both www and non-www subdomains and a separate conf file for each?
Should I use only one of them with permanent redirection?
Why is redirection not working here, do I need some other directive?

Kind regards.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.me.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.me.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.me.crt
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName https://example.me
        ServerAlias www.example.me
        UseCanonicalName Off

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyVia On

        #ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.error.log
        #CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.log combined

       <Proxy *>
               Order deny,allow
               Allow from all
       </Proxy>
        Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.conf

        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mexample.me
        ServerName example.me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        UseCanonicalName Off
        Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.me/"

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyVia On

        #ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.error.log
        #CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tomcat.log combined

       <Proxy *>
               Order deny,allow
               Allow from all
       </Proxy>
        Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.conf

        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

        #ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        #ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you want to know why the redirect does not work you should include your redirect configuration file into the question.

Comment: That redirection contains some two thousand rules with redirection from old website to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that **permanent redirects are cached** by your web browser, so if you made a change and are testing a modified configuration, take pre-cautions and/or adjust your test methodology.  More about that [here](https://serverfault.com/q/1092950/546643).

---

IMHO your configuration is also riddled with errors and incorrect assumptions.

---

## DO NOT ENABLE / ALLOW proxy requests!!!

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
   <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
   </Proxy>
```

The directives above are to create a **forward proxy**. Even worse, it is ***open*** proxy,  that can and will be abused by anybody wants to hide their IP-address using your web server.

You **do not need `ProxyRequests On`** for a ***reverse* proxy** and the `ProxyPass`  directives to work.

Please remove those.

---

In your HTTP VirtualHost

When you only have one VirtualHost it becomes the default VirtualHost (for that port and address). A longer description [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html#hostmatching).  So unless you have additional VirtualHost blocks defined,  this single entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mexample.me
        ServerName example.me
```

will be used for all plain http requests, i.e. both `http://example.me/some-page.htm?foo=bar` , `http://www.example.me` , `http://your.ip-address/` etc. That VirtualHost will be used even when there is no explicit [`ServerAlias www.example.com`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) designating `www.example.com` as an alternate host name for that particular VirtualHost.

```
 Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.me/"
```

Instructs that all requests will result in a redirect response to `https://example.me/`  in other words:

```
 http://example.me/some-page.htm?foo=bar  ==>  https://example.me/some-page.htm?foo=bar
 http://www.example.me                    ==>  https://example.me/
 http://your.ip-address/bob/is.awe-some   ==>  https://example.me/bob/is.awe-some
```

When you redirect everything away it also makes no sense to then have any other directives normally intended to display content in that VirtualHost, so you can omit the `DocumentRoot`, `ProxyPass` etc and keep a very minimal  plain http VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mexample.me
        ServerName example.me
        UseCanonicalName Off

        Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.me/"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

---

In your HTTPS VirtualHost the same holds true: if there are no other VirtualHosts it will be the default used for any request.

The only thing is of course the server TLS certificate; that is only valid for the hostnames included in there, other hostnames will result in an invalid certificate error/warning.

You probably will need to check the contents of the file you include here:

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.conf
```

Comment: Thank you Bob for such a detailed explanation. They are actually using proxy for tomcat and some other app... I  "inherited" this server from someone else and I'm trying to see what is a good practice and how to configure it and why is invalid certificate warning present with www.example.me. Do you maybe see it in this configuration? Should I add another virtualhost for www and link certificate there? Redirect.conf contains some two thousand rules for redirection of data from old to the new website...

Comment: You do not need to have a  forward proxy  enabled when using a reverse proxy or ajp