# curl -X GET http://localhost:9200 return Access Denied

Tags: squid, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to install and setup Elasticsearch 8 on Centos 7 server, the service started but when I do `curl -x GET HTTP://localhost:9200`, or `curl -x GET HTTP://127.0.0.1:9200` or `curl -x GET HTTP://(local IP of the host):9200`, the return is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2016 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
 /*
 * Copyright (C) 1996-2016 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
 *
 * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
 * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
 * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.
 */

/*
 Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
 Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
 http://www.freecsstemplates.org
 Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
*/

/* Page basics */
* {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

html body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #efefef;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #1e1e1e;
}

/* Page displayed title area */
#titles {
        margin-left: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        background: url('/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png') no-repeat left;
}

/* initial title */
#titles h1 {
        color: #000000;
}
#titles h2 {
        color: #000000;
}

/* special event: FTP success page titles */
#titles ftpsuccess {
        background-color:#00ff00;
        width:100%;
}

/* Page displayed body content area */
#content {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #ffffff;
}

/* General text */
p {
}

/* error brief description */
#error p {
}

/* some data which may have caused the problem */
#data {
}

/* the error message received from the system or other software */
#sysmsg {
}

pre {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

/* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
#dirmsg {
    font-family: courier;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#dirlisting {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
    border-bottom: groove;
}
#dirlisting td.size {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* horizontal lines */
hr {
        margin: 0;
}

/* page displayed footer area */
#footer {
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-left: 10px;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id=ERR_ACCESS_DENIED>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:9200/">http://127.0.0.1:9200/</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Access Denied.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_ACCESS_DENIED&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20frontend1%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_ACCESS_DENIED%0D%0AErr%3A%20%5Bnone%5D%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Fri,%2001%20Jul%202022%2013%3A14%3A40%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%20176.119.254.121%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0AGET%20%2F%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AUser-Agent%3A%20curl%2F7.29.0%0D%0AAccept%3A%20*%2F*%0D%0AProxy-Connection%3A%20Keep-Alive%0D%0AHost%3A%20127.0.0.1%3A9200%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">netadmin@birzeit.edu</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Fri, 01 Jul 2022 13:14:40 GMT by frontend1 (squid/3.5.20)</p>
<!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

In elastisearch.yml
Uncomment the following lines and change the value for each line as below.

```
#network.host:(Your IP address)
#http.port: 9200
#node.name: node-1 (or preferred name)
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1 (or preferred name).
```

The firewall service is disabled.

The squid file configuration :

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

How can I solve this problem and get Elastisearch work?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your `curl` command returns a Squid error message suggests one of two things:

1. either Squid and not elasticsearch listens to port 9200.  You can check with  `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :9200` or `sudo ss -tnlp | grep :9200` to which process listens to port 9200
2. alternatively you have configured curl with http proxy settings and you didn't add `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and the systems own IP-address(es) and hostname(s) to the proxy exclude list.
   Unless you're debugging a proxy server you don't use a proxy to connect to services that you can connect to directly.
   Add the `-v` switch to your curl command see for example this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1092951/960939) for an example of the signs that a proxy server is used by curl.
   Set `export no_proxy=internal.example.com,127.0.0.1,localhost` to prevent curl from using the proxy for requests to those hosts.